# Jackson or Gson serialize/deserialize entity with mapKey as the entity

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, gson, deserialization

my Node class

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> parent;
    private HashMap<Node<T>, String> children = new HashMap<>();
}
```

my State class

```
public class State {
    private String name;
    private Boolean endState;
}
```

my Tree class

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private Node<T> root;
    public Tree() {
}

public Tree(T rootData) {
    root = new Node<T>();
    root.setData(rootData);
}

public Node<T> getRoot() {
    return root;
}
```

my Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Tree<State> stateMachine = new Tree<>(new State("q1", false));
        Node<State> q2 = new Node<>(new State("q2", true), stateMachine.getRoot());
        stateMachine.getRoot().addChild(q2, "a");
        stateMachine.getRoot().addChild(stateMachine.getRoot(), "a");

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectMapper().writer().writeValue(os, stateMachine);
        String json = os.toString();
        os.close();

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

the output that i get is

```
{
  "root":{
    "data":{
      "name":"q1",
      "endState":false
    },
    "parent":null,
    "children":{
      "entity.Node@7adf9f5f":"a",
      "entity.Node@85ede7b":"a"
    }
  }
}
```

and I am not sure how to avoid running into infinite recursion and to serialize/deserialize my object completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Json [specification](http://www.json.org/) the keys in a Json String must be Strings. So first of all you have to create custom serializer for your map. Of course you also want to deserialize it, so you will need custom deserializer too.

Then there will be the next problem: during deserialization you want to use the same 'key' object for all occurrences of the same String. So you have to find the already instantiated keys. The easiest way if you store all your Nodes in a list and instead using the Node object itself as a key you can use its position in the List.

This way the keys could be the string representation of Integers and you can also easily create the custom deserialization.

Comment: I already tried to create my own serializer, but I did not manage to stop it at the first generation of nodes, also as it looks to me, I am not getting any advantage for using a library, because in then and I still have to implement it myself, are there not some kind of annotations?

Comment: Refactor the Tree in a way that in contains all of the Nodes in a list. Use the position of the Nodes as key in the maps. This way you don't even need a custom serializer/deserializer. Of course you have to use unique tree.createNode instead of new Node().